# jQuery with ASP.Net UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

What is the best way to ensure that events are rebound after an UpdatePanel callback?

Suggestions I've seen:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args){
    //bind events here.
}
```

or

use the `.live(eventType, handler)` method to initially bind the events

or

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function() {
    //bind events here.
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is event driven, say `click` handlers (or any other bubbling event) for example, use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

If you need things that *aren't* event driven, e.g. plugins, widgets, etc.  Then use `add_endRequest(func)` and run any plugins in there, so they run whenever an `UpdatePanel` finishes (gets new elements after a partial postback).

Comment: If you needed to cover both scenarios, would you want to do both, or would it be acceptable to just go with `add_endRequest(func)`?

Comment: @Homer - I would use `.live()` whenever possible, only put the things that *need* to be run after a partial postback in `add_endRequest`, that's less to run on postback, and a much faster page for your user.